# Como transferir uma variavel javascript para c# aspnet

Tags: javascript, c#

Tenho um javaScript de um projeto aspnet gostaria de saber como faço para transferir o id dessa variável para o código c#

```
 for (var i = 0; i < data.operadores.length; i++) {
                                options += "<option value= '" +
                                    data.operadores[i]['id'] +
                                    "'>" +
                                    data.operadores[i]['userName'] +
                                    "</option >";
                            }
    
    var id = data.operadores[0]['id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Passe esse **id** por ajax em seu script (tô usando jquery no exemplo abaixo):

```
<script>
  $("#btnXxx").click(function () {
    var request = $.ajax({
                    url: "/Home/Teste",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: { id: id },
                    dataType: "html"
                  });

    request.done(function (msg) {
      console.log(msg);
    });
  });
</script>
```

E, então, no seu Controller, crie a função que receberá esse **id**:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<string> Teste(string id)
{
   string msg = "ID: " + id;

   return msg ;
}
```